# How to fill Google form with C#

Tags: c#, .net, google-forms

The form is **multipaged**, like  [this](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSczo-cOJDhEoc0p1399xVVzdRZa13yYlmA5eHqz0ZC72FYImQ/viewform?usp=sf_link)
and I tried to use POST request, but it works only for one-paged form, [check this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33865480/how-do-you-post-data-to-a-multi-page-google-form). Maybe there are another ways?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
var nameValue = new NameValueCollection();
nameValue.Add("entry.xxx", "VALUE");// You will find these in name (not id) attributes of the input tags 
nameValue.Add("entry.xxx", "VALUE");
nameValue.Add("entry.xxx", "VALUE");
nameValue.Add("entry.xxx", "VALUE");
nameValue.Add("pageHistory", "0,1,2");//Comma separated page indexes
Uri uri = new Uri("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/[FORM_ID]/formResponse");
byte[] response = client.UploadValues(uri, "POST", nameValue);
string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
```

I tried this with 3 pages. You can have any number of pages "i guess".
This will submit the data directly and return "Success page from google forms".

EDIT

I Have not worked with google forms "like never", so was not able to find a proper way to do this if there is any, but this seems to work just fine.

Append this to your uri for multiple checkboxes

```
?entry.xxxx=Option+1&entry.xxxx=Option2
```

entry.xxxx remains same for one question
if you have multiple questions with check boxes then it would change to this

```
?entry.xxx=Option+1&entry.xxx=Option2&entry.zzz=Option+1&entry.zzz=Option2
```

value is the lable of your check box
replace (whitespace) with (+) plus if any like in (Option 1)

Comment: Maybe you also know how to set checked more than one checkboxes in a question?

Answer (score 1):

Puneet's answer was the only answer I've found on how to deal with checkboxes with multiple values.  I tried to find a way to put multiple checkbox values in the body of the response instead of in the URL but could not.

In the spirit of his answer, I've made a `GoogleFormSubmissionService` in C# to make dealing with Google Forms easy in C#.

You can find it on my Gist here: [Google Forms Submission Service in C#](https://gist.github.com/ZodmanPerth/be313b8989c7ef191e66b1b0292c2e71?ts=4)

Comment: I'm struggling with Radio boxes instead of checkboxes. Any suggestion on handling Radios?

Comment: I asked my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61849716/481656

Comment: Sorry @HassanGulzar, I haven't had any need to handle radio buttons.